# Merge Dataset performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble with the performance of a MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008. I have read that having indexes on all columns involved on the ON clause will help, but i cannot find how to do that on a dataset that is created just for this operation.

```
MERGE INTO target_table T 
USING (VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?))  AS S (id,unique_code,col1,col2,col3) 
ON ((T.id = S.id) OR (T.unique_code = S.unique_code))

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (unique_code,col1,col2,col3) 
VALUES (S.unique_code,S.col1,S.col2,S.col3) 

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.col1=S.col1,T.col2=S.col2,T.col3=S.col3
```

target_table already have indexes in both "id" and "unique_code" columns.
"unique_code" is a VARCHAR(50) field and can be NULL

Comment: Perhaps a misunderstanding, but the table receiving the data would need to have the index. The incoming data would not have an index (unless using a temp table for example).

Comment: I had same problem too, sql 2008 has problem with merge operation especially with big data. I had had to change it with classic insert update.